# Asignar nombre auto incremental dependiendo de los archivos que seleccione en mi FileUpload asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, fileupload

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para subir comprobantes a Servidor FTP
Actualmente al subir un archivo le asigno el nombre "Comprobante 1" con un string
el problema viene cuando al subir mas de un archivo solo se sube uno en caso de ser del mismo formato y si los formatos son diferentes si los archivos se suben ambos con el nombre "Comprobante 1"

Y lo que necesito es que si selecciono 3 archivos, se suban los 3 con su auto incremental por ejemplo("Comprobante 1","Comprobante 2","Comprobante 3")
Este es mi código actual:

```
                    foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in ftpFileUpload.PostedFiles)
                    {
                        string filename = "Comprobante 1" + extension;

                        Stream fs = uploadedFile.InputStream;
                        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                        byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

                        string filePath = filename;
                        File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(filePath), bytes);

                        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + filename);
                        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "Pass");

                        byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(filePath));

                        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                        {
                            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                        }
                    }
```

¿Existe manera de hacer esto?
De antemano Gracias

Comment: Añade un contador y ese nombre le asignas a filename.

Comment: @fredyfx si me sirvió muchas gracias

Comment: En la parte inferior dice "Tu Respuesta", coloca lo que has realizado para que seas el héroe de más usuarios que tengan el mismo escenario. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada luego de 24 horas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final esta fue la solución de añadir un contador

```
                    int i = 0;    
                    foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in ftpFileUpload.PostedFiles)
                    {

                    i++;
                    string filename = "Comprobante "+ i + extension;

                    Stream fs = uploadedFile.InputStream;
                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                    byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

                    string filePath = filename;
                    File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(filePath), bytes);

                    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + filename);
                    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "Pass");

                    byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(filePath));

                    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                    }
                }
```